# Extracting data from dictionary with a list inside (with more dicts inside)

Tags: python, list, dataframe, dictionary

I have a a `json` file like this. How can I extract this data putting aside Country and just leave `Team` and `Color` as a dataframe?

```
{
  "Country": [
    {
      "Team": "1",
      "color": "blue"
    },
    {
      "Team": "2",
      "color": "red"
    },
    {
      "Team": "3",
      "color": "orange"
    }
  ]
}
```

I don´t know how to handle since it is a `dict` with a `list` inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TRY:

```
import json
import pandas as pd

with open('<json_file_path_here>', 'r') as f:
    d = json.loads(f.read())
    
df = pd.DataFrame(d['Country'])
```

OUTPUT:

```
  Team   color
0    1    blue
1    2     red
2    3  orange
```